# Safari 15 beta javascript confirm / alert / prompt

Tags: javascript, safari

Has anyone tried out Safari 15 beta with Salesforce and also noticed that Javascript alert / confirm / prompt from subframes is not allowed?  I can't find anything in Salesforce's or Apple's documentation about this change.  It appears they picked it up from [a webkit change way back in February](https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/272607/webkit) that has since [been reverted](https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/281848/webkit), but it's not clear if the revert will ship with iOS / Safari 15.

This seems almost identical to the Chrome 92 issues we saw before that change got reverted as well.

Comment: FYI the link syntax is `[display text](url)` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a known issue created for this you can follow:

[Starting with iOS 15 and Safari 15, VF pages using alert, confirm, prompt dialogs will be blocked](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000oYNZQA2)

It seems, initially, that this will be an issue with IOS 15, but the workaround states:

> This will be corrected in an upcoming release of iOS 15

IOS 15 will cause the issue, but iOS 15.1 will revert the change similar to how Chrome eventually did as well.

For now, until 15.1 comes, there's no workaround for mobile and the workaround for desktop/macOs is

> For macOS users running Safari 15, you can temporarily work around
> this issue by enabling the ‘Develop’ menu from Safari Preferences >
> Advanced. Once enabled, you can then select the Develop menu bar item
> at the top of your screen and check ‘Disable Cross-Origin
> Restrictions’. Reload the page you’re on and the prompts will work as
> expected.